# How to build the Cauchy product of $\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{k-1} \right)$?

Tags: analysis

I have to build the Cauchy-product of: $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{k-1} \right).$$

Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the formula for the Cauchy product? It will be more directly applicable if you start by rewriting the second factor as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n$

Comment: Yes I have the formuala but I don't know how to use it. And why ∑∞n=0(n+1)z^n ?

Comment: x @Ulmer: Well, show it! In its usual formulation the formula assumes that the two series you multiply are _already_ phrased with the summation variable being the same as the exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that your first factor is an infinite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Can you rewrite it in a simpler form, using a well-known formula ? Once you've done this, differentiate both sides with regard to *z*. What do you notice ? :-$)$ More spoilers below:

> Your expression is thus of the form $f(x)\cdot f'(x)=\dfrac12\bigg[f^2(x)\bigg]'$. At the same time, $f(x)$, and therefore also $f^2(x)$, are rational functions. Can you expand the latter using [Newton's binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) ? OK, I think I've said more than enough $\ldots$ wouldn't you agree ? ;-$)$